# how to escape findstr /r in a for loop to work in doskey

Tags: for-loop, cmd, escaping, doskey

I have this command

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %a in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /R "Default Gateway[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"') do @ping -t %a
```

this works fine and extracts my default gateway and pings it

I would like to wrap this into a doskey macro called pig (aka ping gateway), but can not escape the findstr correctly. The doskey looks like this (^^ is needed to escape the pipe)

```
doskey pig = for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %a in ('ipconfig ^^| findstr /R "Default Gateway[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"') do @ping -t %a
```

With this however the doskey does not even register and findstr generates this output

```
FINDSTR: Cannot open do
FINDSTR: Cannot open @ping
FINDSTR: Cannot open -t
FINDSTR: Cannot open %a
```

I found out that escaping the last double quote allows for registering the doskey, but if I call the pig, it just outputs this:

```
More?
```

My imagination ends here and the machine just asks me for more...

I would like to have a doskey macro which looks up the gateway and pings it for me

Comment: The first thing you should understand, is that your `findstr.exe` command, which you state is working is simply working by luck. I would advise that you open a Command Prompt window, type `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, to learn its options.

Comment: The command should probably look more like this: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\doskey.exe pig=For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe 2^^^>NUL ^^^| %SystemRoot\System32\findstr.exe /L /I /C:"Default Gateway"') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -t%H```. Please be advised that `Default` and `Gateway` are English strings, so using them on non English language configured systems will not produce the result you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - It's important where you want to put your definition, on the command line or in a batch file. The syntax for the line will be different

Second - It's important to see what you get.
You should look into the defined macro with `doskey /macros`

If I use your sample on the command line I get:

```
pig=for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %a in ('ipconfig ^
```

If I use it in a batch file I get:

```
pig=for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" a
```

For the command line you need to use (Three instead of two carets):

```
doskey pig=for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %a in ('ipconfig ^^^| findstr /R "Default Gateway[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"') do @ping -t %a
```

Inside a batch file use (The percent signs has to be doubled, too):

```
doskey pig=for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^^^| findstr /R "Default Gateway[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"') do @ping -t %%a
```